# How to handle timeout exception when using jms outbound gateway?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a jms outbound gateway like this:

```
<jms:outbound-gateway request-destination = "requestQueue"
    reply-destination="replayQueue"
    request-channel="sendToJmsChannel"
    reply-channel="receiveFromJmsChannel" 
    receive-timeout="5000"/>
```

In my spring integration flow I send requests to 'sendToJmsChannel' and handle replies from 'receiveFromJmsChannel'

The question is, how can I handle the case when the `receive-timeout` is elapsed and no reply was returned to the `reply-destination`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JmsOutboundGateway` thorws:

```
throw new MessageTimeoutException(message,
                        "failed to receive JMS response within timeout of: " + this.receiveTimeout + "ms");
```

In case of that timeout (5 sec by default).

You can configure `<retry-advice>` within `<request-handler-advice-chain>` for the `<jms:outbound-gateway>` to resend the same message to the `request-destination` on that `MessageTimeoutException`. Or just handle it from the caller with regular `try...catch`, or in the `ErrorHandler` on the `error-channel`, if your flow starts from the `<poller>` or `message-driven-ednpoint`.

Otherwise it isn't clear what is your goal. The Exception in the Spring Integration doesn't provide more complexity as it is in the typical Java application.